# Should I use ScrollView or RecyclerView for scrolling in fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a question about my Android app. I have a fragment in which I want to scroll. Should I use the ScrollView in the fragment or in the main activity (the fragment is used for navigation in toolbar)?

Also, should I use ScrollView or RecyclerView? Here is what I tried so far, but it didn't work.
This is the main activity xml, where I added the ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomAppBar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green_700"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/light_grey"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/light_grey"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@font/josefin_sans_semibold"
            android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onPressFab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is the fragment where I need scrolling. It is the home fragment from toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green_700"
        app:cardElevation="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.428"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_outline"
                android:fontFamily="@font/josefin_sans_semibold"
                android:hint="Search Barcode"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.183"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sbutton"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="138dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome back!"
        android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I would be grateful if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: what? recylerview for scrolling? 
does your scrollview nor scrolling or not scrolling properly?

Comment: it doesn't scroll at all

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: actually I am unable to evaluate the issue but what is understand is that you should use scroll view in your fragment not in your activity.

Comment: Try with android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView as the root of your fragment and remove the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is used to make lists.

Try put yout fragment code inside a ScrollView and remove it from your activity.